# Pandas: how to convert a cell with multiple values to multiple row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Name asn
Org1 asn1,asn2
org2 asn3
org3 asn4,asn5
```

I would like to convert my DataFrame to look like this:

```
Name asn
Org1 asn1
Org1 asn2
org2 asn3
org3 asn4
Org3 asn5
```

Does anybody know how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your starting DataFrame is named `df`, you could write:

```
>>> df2 = df.asn.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)          # break df.asn into columns
>>> df2.index = df.Name                                   # set the index as df.Name
>>> df2 = df2.stack().reset_index('Name')                 # stack and reset_index
>>> df2
    Name       0
0   Org1    asn1
1   Org1    asn2
0   org2    asn3
0   org3    asn4
1   org3    asn5
```

All that's left to do is rename the column:

```
df2.rename(columns={0: 'asn'}, inplace=True)
```

Depending on your next move, you may also want to set a more useful index.

Comment: Nice. You can also avoid the `drop('level_1', axis=1)` by using `reset_index('Name')`.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu, that looks a lot neater.

Comment: @ajcr.Thanks. ONe question, what if I have three columns? a third column which I like to be like the 'Name' column

Answer (score 2):

Just spent hours dealing with this and discovered that the [explode function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) is a much simpler solution.

First replace the strings in the multi-valued cells with lists like this:

```
    asn_lists = df.asn.str.split(',')         # split strings into list
    df.asn = asn_lists                        # replace strings with lists in the dataframe
```

And the just use the explode function:

```
    df2 = df.explode('asn') # explode based on the production_companies column
```

This solution will also work for larger dataframes with extra columns